# unable to convert string to float

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read from the csv and then convert the string values to float but I'm running into an error when it tries to compile to stof:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stof: no conversion/bin/sh.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // STEP 1

    ifstream inFS;
    string line;
    string rm_in, medv_in;
    const int MAX_LEN = 1000;
    vector<double> rm(MAX_LEN);
    vector<double> medv(MAX_LEN);

    cout<< "Opening file titanic.csv" << endl;

    inFS.open("titanic_project.csv");
    if(!inFS.is_open()){
        cout<<"Could not open file"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout<<"Reading line 1"<<endl;
    getline(inFS, line);

    cout<<"Data Observation"<<endl;

    int numObservations = 0;
    while (inFS.good()){

        getline(inFS, rm_in, ',');
        getline(inFS, medv_in, '\n');


        rm.at(numObservations) = stof(rm_in);
        medv.at(numObservations) = stof(medv_in);

   }
```

This is what the Titanic.csv looks like:

```
"","pclass","survived","sex","age"
"738",3,0,1,19
"868",3,1,0,22
"971",3,1,1,20
"938",3,0,0,1
"456",2,0,1,63
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or does the `rm_in` string contain the two double-quote characters? That would likely mess up the `stof` call, is not?

Comment: *but I'm running into an error when it tries to compile to stof:* -- That is a runtime error, not a compiler error.  You should be using your debugger, or at the very least, print out what data you're trying to use `stof` for.

Comment: You should check for errors after reading from the file and before using the values.

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on any of the proposed solutions?

Comment: I should clarify and say that my objective is to get all the numbers in the 'survived' column in a vector and all the numbers in the 'pclass' column in one vector. How would I go about doing that

Answer (score 1):

You should note that even in your example you have `""`. Which will be passed as an argument in `stof()`. So you may want to watch out for unexpected values using [try-catch block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch):

```
// ...
try {
    rm.at(numObservations) = stof(rm_in);
    medv.at(numObservations) = stof(medv_in);
}
catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {}
// ...
```

Consider this as a simplified example:

```
std::string s; // Empty string
double d = stof(s); // Will throw an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
```

Comment: I should clarify and say that my objective is to get all the numbers in the 'survived' column in a vector and all the numbers in the 'pclass' column in one vector. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @mustafank  I should say that it does not have anything to do with the question at hand, the thrown exception, which a presume has been answered. As to the objective, I would advise you to create a `vector<int>` to hold all the data for a person, populate a `vector<vector<int>>` with these, with appropriate formatting (`stoi()`). Then you are free to do whatever you need to be done with the data.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you argument can't be converted (and the application throws exception that you didn't catch).
Check value of rm_in.